# How do I update a foreign key (belongsTo) in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, model, sequelize.js, belongs-to

I have the following model:

```
'use strict';
const {Model} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Key extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Key.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      });
    }
  };
  Key.init({
    keyType: DataTypes.STRING,
    key: DataTypes.JSON
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Key',
  });
  return Key;
};
```

I then try to create a row, after receiving `userId`, `keyType` and `key`:

```
...
const Key = KeyModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
const createKey = async (userid, keyType, key) => {
  const result = await Key.create({userId, keyType, key});
  return result;
}
```

The row gets created successfully in the DB, and i get back an ID (the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are updated as well), but the `userId` is null.

How should I pass it to the `create` method so the value gets to the DB? Am I missing something in the model?

PS: the DB is MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change your code like below.

```
'use strict';
const {Model} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Key extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Key.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'keyId',
        targetKey: 'userId'
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      });
    }
  };
  Key.init({
    keyId: DataTypes.STRING,
    keyType: DataTypes.STRING,
    key: DataTypes.JSON
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Key',
  });
  return Key;
};

const Key = KeyModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
const createKey = async (userId, keyType, key) => {
  const result = await Key.create({keyId: userId, keyType, key});
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I should add the foreign key to the model explicitly? That negates the need for the association. The migration, that was created automatically, already has a userId field defined.

Comment: My thought is, that it should be a foreignkey - column at key table and a targetkey - column at user table. So i added a column keyId to key model.

Comment: Upon further research, it looks like I may need to explicitly add the foreign key field to my model, so I'll mark your answer correct. I'm not really thrilled with it, but it's time to move on. Thanks for taking the time to answer!